# Kafka Stream Topology on multiple instances

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

We have a streams topology that will work on multiple machines. We are storing time-windowed aggregation results into state stores.
Since state stores are storing local data, aggregation should be done on another topic for overall aggregation, I think.
But it seems like I am missing something because none of the examples do the overall aggregations on another KStream or Processor.

Do we need to use the groupBy logic for storing overall aggregation, or use a GlobalKtable or just implement our own merger code somewehere?

What is the correct architecture for this?

In below code, I have tried to group all the messages coming to the processor with a constant key to store the overall aggregation on just one machine, but it would lose the parallelism that Kafka supplies, I think.

```
dashboardItemProcessor = streamsBuilder.stream("Topic25", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), eventSerde))
        .filter((key, event) -> event != null && event.getClientCreationDate() != null);

 dashboardItemProcessor.map((key, event) -> KeyValue.pair(key, event.getClientCreationDate().toInstant().toEpochMilli()))
       .groupBy((key, event) -> "count", Serialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))
       .windowedBy(timeWindow)
       .count(Materialized.as(dashboardItemUtil.getStoreName(itemId, timeWindow)));
```

Comment: As soon as you need to group the keys, you're effectively funneling in all the data to one processor, regardless of the the framework used (for example, if you did the same thing in Spark). It's not really clear why you need to group everything and "re-key" it

Comment: So you say, we don't have to manually merge the results coming from different instances of the same topology?

Comment: It's not clear to mean what data you're getting or expecting as output. If you want something to be parallelized, though, ideally it wouldn't be the "wordcount" example where the word is only "count". For example, you might want to count by `event.getName()` or `event.getClientUuid()`, or similar, but like I said, I don't know your data

Answer (score 0):

> In below code, I have tried to group all the messages coming to the processor with a constant key to store the overall aggregation on just one machine, but it would lose the parallelism that Kafka supplies, I think.

This seems to be the right approach. And yes, you loos parallelism, but that is how an global aggregation work. In the end, one machine must compute it...

What you could improve though, is to do a two step approach: ie, first aggregate by "random" keys in parallel, and use a second step with only one key to "merge" the partial aggregates into a single one. This way, some parts of the computation are parallelized and only the final step (on hopefully reduced data load) is non-parallel. Using Kafka Streams, you need to implement this approach "manually".

Comment: So, we should deploy the reducer processor as a separate module and don't scale that?

Comment: You would have two reducers. You can still deploy both in one application -- if you set a singleton-key after the first reduce, all data will go to a single instance of the second reducer anyway.